# The general process of creating a printable pdf from xml

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

This is a very, very basic question. I'm self-taught using html, xml and css, so please forgive my absolute ignorance. My situation is as follows: I Know how to write XMl files, I can create the html output I want and use Css to style the page the way I need to. Now, I would like to print a book from this result. I need it to split the content of my html page into A4-pages, add page numbers and line numbers. What techniques do I have to learn to do this? I have read online that xsl:fo is used to transform xml to pdf. Is there any way I could use the html/css output with this or do I need to write an entire new stylesheet using xsl:fo?  Do I need to learn javascript? I'm willing to do any of this, I just don't know where to start.

I had a look at importing my xml file into indesign and that would work, but then I'd have to do all the work of styling the text again. There has to be a better way.

Comment: I am afraid this question is off-topic for SO, but you will find plenty of options if you search the web for "html to pdf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use CSS to style your print output, the proprietary [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) seems to be the only tool that generates decent typography.

Turning to open source tooling, you could use XSLT to transform your custom XML to XSL-FO and then [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to generate the PDF, however the output is not so clean as with TeX and you'd need to specify all your layout in XSL-FO instead of CSS as well.

What I'd recommend is transforming your XML to (HTML or [DocBook XML](http://docbook.org/tdg51/en/html/)) and then use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to turn that into a PDF. Pandoc uses either pdflatex, xetex or luatex to generate the PDF. If you're not familiar with the LaTeX macro package, I recommend using the [ConTeXt](http://www.contextgarden.net) macro package instead, which has more consistent layout commands and doesn't rely on packages for basic functionality. To change the layout, use a custom [Pandoc template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates) file to generate the desired ConTeXt file. That would work as follows:

```
$ saxon -o docbook-file.xml custom.xml stylesheet.xslt #generate DocBook
$ pandoc -f docbook docbook-file.xml -t context --standalone --template template.tex -o out.tex #generate ConTeXt
$ context out.tex #generate PDF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had seen Prince XML and had been wondering if it would do what I want. I'll try using it, but I'm also new to command line. I have the oxygen xml editor, doesn't that do something similar? Your answer is already a little too complicated for me, I'm still confused.  Do I need to abandon all my stylesheets I wrote to create the html and write something completely new for the pdf using xsl-fo?

Comment: With PrinceXML I think you can just use your HTML, but the other approaches all require something else, so yes, you'll have to write new stylesheets to transform your custom XML to either XSL-FO XML or DocBook XML. The saxon command in my example does the same thing as what you do in Oxygen: do a XSLT transform.

Answer (score 0):

Or look here http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf which uses XSL FO hidden to the user. You style with CSS. There are many samples showing book features like headers/footers, page numbering,  multiple sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://pdfcrowd.com/ - very simple and easy. I'm using their java API and it's smooth. Also quite cheap.